# Pronouncing "found" as "fyound": why?

Tags: pronunciation

I had a teacher in high school who spoke like that, and an elderly neighbor: both women. When I first read Tom Wolfe's novel *A Man in Full*, I ran across this passage:

> "You must be Mr. DeCyasi," she said, extending her hand. "I'm Louise Gyardner."
>   At first Conrad had taken it to be a speech defect. In fact, as he soon deduced, it was an affectation, and a minor one at that.

So it's an affectation. Fine. Who would teach people (young women?) to speak like that and why?

Comment: I've never heard this. I wonder if it might be a hypercorrection generalising on the pronunciation of words like "due" and "duty"; i.e. somebody regards "doo" and "dooty" as substandard and substitutes "dyoo" and "dyooty", and then generalses this to other consonants and vowels. I don't know where else this would arise from.

Comment: With **fyound** are you trying to represent that the vowel was a nasalized dipthong (fay-und) or that she palatalized, as in "yikes"?  Or is that a sound like "fie"?

Comment: @ColinFine: It might be. If it were just one person, I'd write it off as an individual quirk, but there seems to be a pattern.

Comment: I think it's an attempt to reflect the southern (Atlanta) accent. The -r- in "Gardner" affects the vowel.

Comment: @TimRomano: More like the latter. It's almost as if they inserted an "ee" sound between the consonant and the vowel. And not just any consonant, either: it's always a "g," "c," or "f." Go figure.

Comment: @TimRomano: Hmm. I don't know. My high school teacher was from Long Island, I think, and teaching in Queens. I only remember her vaguely, but she did have "big hair."

Comment: In my neck of the woods (PA), there's a lot of nasalization; back vowels are brought forward so that **found** often sounds like "feelnd".  You can heard this in the Baltimore accent as well.

Comment: @TimRomano: Yeah, no, that's not quite the same. Some of my Philly friends speak as if they'd just spent ten years in Provence, but they don't say "f-y-ound."

Comment: I think the *y* in the quote is only a representation of something going on in the pronunciation. If it's reduced to **almost** nothing, almost just as an aspiration or a softening of the preceding consonant, it becomes a reasonable approximation of RP.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: That's a very good point. The consonants were, in fact, softened by it. What's RP?

Comment: RP=Received Pronunciation. Have a look at [the Queen in 1957](https://youtu.be/mBRP-o6Q85s?t=30s) and compare the word "messages" after she mentions her grandfather.

Comment: Is Louise Gardner a southerner?

Comment: @TimRomano: I ... uh ... I believe she is. Atlanta, unless I'm much mistaken. Note, however, that Conrad, who hails from Atlanta as well, takes it for a speech defect at first. Oh, and Tom Wolfe, a quintessential New Yorker, is from the South too.

Comment: Good point about Conrad hearing something strange in it. But the sounds represented by the spelling are not clear, and we are only guessing at what they might be. We don't know if the -y- represents the vowel in "rice" or if it's a palatal like "yard" or just an aspiration or softening as Andrew suggests.  But if Louise,  a southerner, were speaking with a British accent, I doubt Conrad would consider it a "minor affectation" or would  have thought it a "speech defect".

Comment: @TimRomano: I believe Andrew is on the right track. Maybe I should just call the author. He must be in a lousy mood right now, though. His last novel didn't do so well (even though, in my less-than-modest opinion, it was pretty good, and anyway, no one's novels are doing well these days).

Comment: I took it to represent a palatalised consonant (as in Russian or Irish).

Comment: @ColinFine: This is like an epiphany for me. Would you say that the difference between _pew_ and _poo_ is that in the former the consonant is softened by the palatalization of the vowel?

Comment: Well, no, @Ricky, I wouldn't, because I avoid ill-defined and ambiguous descriptions such as "softened". I'm not sure that it is accurate to describe the difference between 'pew' and 'poo' as palatalisation of the consonant - it's more a diphthongisation of the vowel, though palatalisation will almost certainly result. But I was guessing that palatalisation was what you were reporting in the original question. "Palatalisation of the vowel" doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @ColinFine: Doesn't diphthongization nearly always involve some degree of palatilization? Pardon me for being slow today.

Comment: @Ricky: if it introduces a high front vowel, it will usually palatalise the preceding consonant, yes.

Comment: It reminds me of a Russian or Slawic characteristic. Peter becomes Pjoter.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, Thanks for the clip of the Queen 60 years ago,  Biggest surprise to me is that she pronounces 'television' the modern way, single stress on the first syllable.  I could've sworn that we Brits double-stressed it in those days  -  first and third syllable.

Comment: In this comic "fyound" is used by someone (in northern England) pretending to be upper class: https://www.gocomics.com/bad-machinery/2017/05/06

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The historical phenomenon of palatalizing the velar consonants /k/ and /g/ before certain vowel sounds

I actually don't think Louise "Gyardner" would necessarily pronounce *found* as "fyound". My impression is that the kind of palatalization that  Wolfe is describing in this passage only occured after the velar consonants /g/ and /k/, before certain vowel sounds that either had a phonetically "front" quality, or that historically had had a "front" quality. Specifically:

- I'm sure I remember reading that it occured before the sound /æ/, as in "cat" ("kyat").
- It also seemed to have occured before "ar" pronounced /ɑr/, as in your example of "Gyardner"; I guess the explanation for this is that the palatalization originated before "a" was turned into a back vowel [ɑ] in this position.
- For at least some speakers, it occured before the a-starting diphthong /aɪ/, as in "kind" ("kyind").
- I found one source that indicates that "k" could also be heard palatalized before the diphthong /aʊ/, as in "cow" (*[A Defence of Phonetic Spelling](https://books.google.com/books?id=2mgXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=%22kyind%22&source=bl&ots=nl_As9Beti&sig=Bc2-e0U4U0V6kLdsNJ5FzlhM-Lk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj356Cuw9DWAhVhslQKHfLcCBw4ChDoAQhFMAk#v=onepage&q=%22kyind%22&f=false),* by Robert Gordon Latham, 1872), but I'm not sure if that pronunciation might have a slightly different distribution, or different origin.
- It seems it could occur, although not as noticeably since the difference between the quality of the glide and the following vowel sound was smaller, before the front vowels /ɪ/ and /iː/ (e.g. Latham refers to "kin" being pronounced as "kyin").

Phonetically, velar consonants are often more prone to palatalization than others, and since the vowel /æ/ is phonetically "front", it is possible for it to impart a palatal quality to the preceding consonant. Similar phenomena exist (or have existed) in other languages: in French, /k/ and /g/ were palatalized before /a/, resulting ultimately in fricatives /ʃ/ and /ʒ/ as in *chat* "cat" and *jardin* "garden"; in Japanese, English loanwords that contain /kæ/ or /gæ/ are often adopted with palatalized consonants.

As mentioned in the extract, palatalizing velars before certain vowels became thought of as a kind of affection and seems to have passed out of common use in standard accents a long time ago; however, it apparently survives in some less well-known accents, like Jamaican English (*[Culture and Customs of Jamaica](https://books.google.com/books?id=jfNa8sr3lAEC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=cat%20kyat%20pronunciation&source=bl&ots=oiszUHqXO3&sig=MIBDT8tFlJWPvZK9nIHiYzRETKc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYyvGcx9DWAhVDl1QKHRq9B1UQ6AEIODAF#v=onepage&q=cat%20kyat%20pronunciation&f=false),* by Martin Mordecai and Pamela Mordecai, 2001).

You can find references to this phenomenon in [Walker (1791)](https://archive.org/stream/acriticalpronou00conggoog#page/n42/mode/2up/search/kyind), among other sources, so it's pretty old and existed in British English as well as in American English.

#### "Fyound" might occur due to unconditional fronting of the first part of the diphthong /aʊ/

Since /f/ is not a velar sound, it doesn't participate in the sound change I described in the previous section. This section is just speculation, but if it's true that some people pronounce "found" in a way that sounds like "fyound", I think it is likely that this pronunciation is the result of fronting the first element of the dipthong /aʊ/, changing it to something like /æʊ/, which then develops a front onglide /jæʊ/ unconditionally. There are known to be accents of American English where the "cat" vowel has developed more or less unconditionally, not just after velars, to a diphthong with a very front first element (the Wikipedia article on the [Northern Cities Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Cities_Vowel_Shift#Raising_and_tensing_of_.2F.C3.A6.2F) says "*cat* **and *that*** as pronounced by a Rochester, New York resident may sound like "kyet" **and "thyet"** to a visitor") and it seems possible that this could also occur in some accents for the "mouth" diphthong. However, I am not familar with any description of an accent that has this feature.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the two are related.

Comment: @Ricky: Hmm, I'll try to see if I can find something that mentions "fyound"

Answer (score 4):

It’s a regional accent. The way you speak sounds outrageous to people who grew up in a different area than you also.

Comment: I appreciate that. Which region, though?

Comment: Without more context, it's hard to tell.  There's an accent once common in remote parts of New England (NE US) - now almost extinct, thanks to TV and so forth - in which "car" is rendered something like "kyar," and "cow" something like "kyow." The sound blends eh-ah-oo.

Comment: To my Midwestern US ears the "Boston" accent of Norm Abram seems to have this feature (though it's minor compared to the strength of his non-rhotic twists).  (I'm sure Bostonians would object on all counts, however.)