# Why does Tom Hanks pronounce "stupid" as "st-you-pid" in "The Bonfire of the Vanities"?

Tags: pronunciation, yod-dropping

This may or may not related to [my previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301765/pronouncing-found-as-fyound-why). In this movie (which is based on another one of Tom Wolfe's novels, *The Bonfire of the Vanities*), Tom Hanks plays the lead character who is an Ivy League graduate. He doesn't make much of an effort to imitate any of the Harvard, Yale, or Princeton speech patterns and tones, but he does insist on pronouncing the word "stupid" as "styoopid." Why? Where do they speak like that?

[image]

He's not trying to copy or parody the so-called Mid-Atlantic accent: one, it was already out of vogue in the 1990's, and, two, that's not how Mid-Atlantic sounds, anyway. What *is* he doing? What point is he trying to get across?

Comment: haven't seen the movie, but your spelling and his age in the photo makes me think of Forest Gump.. Does he say it like in Forest Gump? if so, maybe he recently finished filming that movie, and simply slipped.

Comment: @Born2Smile: Actually, "Bonfire" came fully four years _before_ "Forrest Gump."

Comment: That word is often mispronounced to emphasize the stupidity present.  Eg, not just "stupid" but "stoooopid".

Comment: @Ricky yeah, I see your point.. that would've been one huge slip-up for it to have propagated backwards in time :)

Comment: @HotLicks: No, no. St-yoopid, not stoooopid.

Comment: There are various ways one might intentionally mispronounce it.  If I read "styoopid" correctly it's said with a sort of sneer -- a Trump face.

Comment: @Ricky do you mean St U-pid? I pronounce it like that, with a u like in unicorn

Comment: @HotLicks: Yeah, well, Hanks says it when he's trying his best to get out of a very bad post-apocalyptic-looking neighborhood in his brand-new Mercedes, with his mistress in the passenger seat, with horror in his eyes he's not even attempting to conceal, "All I'm saying is we shouldn't do anything st-yoopid," - words to that effect. And then he repeats it.

Comment: @Born2Smile: Yep.

Comment: @Born2Smile: Or st-you-pid.

Comment: I do recall that Hanks is fond of such pronunciations.  I'm sure he can pronounce the word "normally" if he wishes, so you'd have to ask Hanks and the director why he chose that one in that situation.

Comment: @HotLicks: He's pretty well-trained, actually. He can do any regional accent at will. It was obviously the director's choice. The movie, for all its shortcomings, and not being faithful to the novel, isn't half-bad. It flopped big time, and I don't even know why.

Comment: Maybe because it was styoopid.

Comment: The phenomenon in question is *u-palatalization:* [this recent blog post from Oxford University Press](http://blog.oup.com/2016/01/how-pronounce-pulitzer/) discusses it reasonably well and briefly. "[I]t turns out that the palatalized versions of many common words are often the older forms, still used among many speakers of British and Canadian English. Thus you hear palatalized due, tune, dune, news, lewd, and so on. Twentieth-century American speech tended to drop these palatal glides." And more British, to some Americans, means higher class; and the novel and film are largely about class.

Comment: What do you mean by "that's not how Mid-Atlantic sounds, anyway"? Did Mid-Atlantic normally drop the y-sound in words like *stupid* and *tune*?

Comment: @sumelic: I'm still a bit confused about this whole palatalization thing. An average Manhattanite will soften the consonant in words like _tune_ and _news_, but no one I know says t-you-n, I need a little time to figure this out. I certainly know a lot more about it right now than I did yesterday, thanks to all the help I got here. Great stuff!

Comment: I was quite surprised by this question since I consider this to be very much the standard pronunciation. It's how I learned it in Germany, and I am sure it's also how basically everyone pronounces it in the UK, where I have lived for a few years. Presumably you consider the 'stoopid' pronunciation standard? I always thought this was a simplified variant only common in the US, and not universally used even there.

Comment: Not to take anything away from Araucaria's great answer, but my reaction was similar to Hot Licks'.  Words used in a derogatory way are often exaggerated in various ways.  One is to extend it, like "stuuuupid".  Another is to turn a single syllable into multiple, artificial syllables by introducing a nonsense vowel, like "steeyupid".

Answer (score 10):

A yod is another name for the sound/j/, the first sound in the word *yes*.

Very many varieties of English have a yod in the word *stupid*. For example, the transcription for *stupid* given by the [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stupid) is:

- /ˈstjuː.pɪd/  ("styoopid")

For many speakers there will be coalescent assimilation between the /t/ and the /j/ giving the following pronunciation:

- /ˈstʃuː.pɪd/ ("schoopid")

The /tʃ/ here is the same sound that we find at the beginning of the word *chip*.

In most but not all varieties of American English, this yod has disappeared from the word. There are very many words which have lost their yods over the last century or so in American English, but which retain them in other varieties including Southern Standard British English. These yods have become dropped chiefly in words beginning with alveolar consonants /t, d, n, l, s, z/. So for example for many Americans the word *news* is pronounced: /nuːz/, "nooze" whereas SSBE speakers say:/njuːz/ "nyooze".

So, in fact we could kind of turn the Original Poster's question on its head. It's not a question of where this yod came from, it's a question of where all the other ones went! It seems just that Hanks' character speaks a variety of English where the original yod is still present.

---

[This blog on yod-dropping](http://dialectblog.com/2011/09/06/yod-dropping/) may interest readers.